# Wrong time for `execution_time()` function

Tags: php, function, date, time, execution-time

```
public function execution_time($begin = null)
{
    if($begin == null){
        return microtime(true);
    }
    else {
        $result = date("H:i:s", microtime(true) - $begin);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to count the execution time.
But the problem is when execution time is lesser then 1 hour, it writes wrong timestamp, for example:

```
$timeBegin = execution_time();
sleep(8);
$time_end = execution_time($timeBegin); // it shows 06:00:08
```

It lasts only 8 seconds, why 6 hours are appear? Why this happens and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 6 hours difference because of your timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Line, sets time zone to UTC and eliminates the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in your script:

`date_default_timezone_set`

Here is the working example

https://codebrace.com/editor/b16b092fb